# Align caption next to table that is below another table

Tags: tables, formatting

I have the following code:

```latex
\begin{table}[]
\begin{varwidth}{\columnwidth}
\setlength{\lineskip}{5.4pt}\raggedright

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-7}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{FDDI} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM5} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Core\\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 62.5 & 50 & 50 & 50 & 50 & 50 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cladding \\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 125 & 125 & 125 & 125 & 125 & 125 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Bandwidth-\\ distance product(s)\\ (Mhz $\cdot$ km)\end{tabular}} & 160 & 200 & 500 & 1500 & 3500 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3500\\ @ 850nm\\ 1850\\ @ 950 nm\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Light \\ wavelength(s) (nm)\end{tabular}} & 850 & 850 & 850 & 850 & 850 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}850\\ 950\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OS1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OS2} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Core\\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 9 & 9 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cladding \\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 125 & 125 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Attenuation\\ (dB / km)\end{tabular}} & 1.0 & 0.4 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Light \\ wavelength(s) (nm)\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1310\\ 1550\end{tabular} & 1550 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table of common fibre types used in industry for speeds up to 40 Gbit/s. OM3, OM4 and OM5 are described as "Laser-optimized", and make use of the aformentioned VCSELs instead of LEDs for transmission. \cite{orlyethernet}}\label{tab:multimodesinglemodefibres}%
\end{varwidth}
\end{table}
```

It produces this output:
[image: obtained]

I would like to put the caption beside the 2nd table, aligned at the bottom (or middle, which might look better), like so:

[image: actual]

How can I achieve this? The tables need to be somehow grouped so they don't separate from each other. I have tried using a SCtable but that puts the caption to the right of both tables, off-screen, so doesn't work.

(ignore the missing 1310, as well as OS1/OS2 being "multi mode", my mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{varwidth}{\columnwidth}
\setlength{\lineskip}{5.4pt}\raggedright

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-7}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{FDDI} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OM5} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Core\\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 62.5 & 50 & 50 & 50 & 50 & 50 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cladding \\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 125 & 125 & 125 & 125 & 125 & 125 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Bandwidth-\\ distance product(s)\\ (Mhz $\cdot$ km)\end{tabular}} & 160 & 200 & 500 & 1500 & 3500 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3500\\ @ 850nm\\ 1850\\ @ 950 nm\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Light \\ wavelength(s) (nm)\end{tabular}} & 850 & 850 & 850 & 850 & 850 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}850\\ 950\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{minipage}{.55\linewidth}%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OS1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{OS2} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Type} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Multi-mode} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Core\\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 9 & 9 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cladding \\ diameter ($\mu$m)\end{tabular}} & 125 & 125 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Attenuation\\ (dB / km)\end{tabular}} & 1.0 & 0.4 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Light \\ wavelength(s) (nm)\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1310\\ 1550\end{tabular} & 1550 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}%
\caption{A table of common fibre types used in industry for speeds up to 40 Gbit/s. OM3, OM4 and OM5 are described as "Laser-optimized", and make use of the aformentioned VCSELs instead of LEDs for transmission. \cite{orlyethernet}}\label{tab:multimodesinglemodefibres}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\end{varwidth}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is close, but it seems to align the text to the right as seen here, how can this be changed to be on the left with a small margin? [https://i.imgur.com/pSbdacf.png](https://i.imgur.com/pSbdacf.png)

Comment: @Neo This can be controlled via the width of the minipages. I cannot know which value will work for you because I don't know which documentclass you use, which page geometry you have etc.

Comment: Your edit works, changing the .55 value next to the first minipage can change the horizontal alignment. Thanks!